# Filters are not pushed down across lateral view

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive").appName("Write ORC File").getOrCreate()
spark.sql('drop TABLE if exists test').show()
spark.sql('CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (request struct<characteristic:array<struct<id:string,value:string>>>)'
'ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde" '
'STORED AS INPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat" '
'OUTPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat" '
'LOCATION "testfolder"').show()
spark.sql("select request from test lateral view explode(request.characteristic) cTable as c where c.value='79640000000'").explain()
```

shows no PushedFilters:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [request#2]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(c#4.value) AND (c#4.value = 79640000000))
   +- *(1) Generate explode(request#2.characteristic), [request#2], false, [c#4]
      +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
         +- FileScan orc spark_catalog.default.test[request#2] 
Batched: true, 
DataFilters: [], 
Format: ORC, 
Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/Users/paf/Downloads/spark-warehouse/testfolder], 
PartitionFilters: [], 
PushedFilters: [], 
ReadSchema: struct<request:struct<characteristic:array<struct<id:string,value:string>>>>
```

So is executed extremely slow, full scan.

Suppose I search for a column value, which is totally out of min/max statistics range.
Search could have been much faster, but no.

I fully expected nested column to be filtered at a FileScan level. To skip whole ORC files/stripes/blocks of rows, if they don't match stats (min/max/bloom filter).

Looks like a lack of useful feature (aka bug) in Spark, [filed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-45876).

Any ideas if this could be fixed by adding some [external strategy](https://medium.com/@vladimir.prus/advanced-custom-operators-in-spark-79b12da61ca7) or something?

Thanks!